# jquery animation doesn't work in opera and chrome

Tags: jquery, carousel, jquery-slider

I have strange behavior with Jquery. Please open http://westminster.percipio.me/index2 in firefox, it should slide screens and also panel a bit bottom "    University of Westminster    Courses    News    Business    Schools    Alumni" also animated and works as need. Then if you open in opera or chrome animation with slides will not work. Please help me figure it out.Thanks

Comment: Wow, there's some strange HTML in there: <a href="?cat=&amp;panel=left" id="rightNav" class="navlink" style="z-index: 9999; "><i class="icon-next icon-large white"></i></a> - why not just add a class to the anchor and use the CSS background there?

Comment: Add Safari to your list of browsers where it does not work.

Comment: Your code is a mess.   Please post the relevant JavaScript and HTML within the question.  Why include the Slider JS within the middle of the page?  Also, why write the slider code from scratch when so many solid jQuery slider plugins are available?

Comment: client wants exactly that implantation and I couldn't find appropriate slider for that. He wants slider as on bbc.co.uk they provide their glow api but it is very heavy and I couldn't set it properly. Also need to work it in js off mode

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in left offset value. Opera returns left offset like `auto` against FF is 0px. Just need add a check `left_indent = isNaN(left_indent) ? 0 : left_indent;`